# Sortbyname cannot be resolved to a type in java

Tags: java

Error:

> Sortbyname cannot be resolved to a type in java

I am using the Comparator interface method by sorting the name and score for cricket players using in java.

I am a beginner in java

```
package javapractice2;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Player {
    String player_name;
    int player_score;

    public Player(String member, int score) {
        this.player_name = member;
        this.player_score = score;
    }
}
```

/**Comparator**/

```
package javapractice2;
import java.util.*;
public class NameComparator {

    public class Sortbyname implements Comparator<Player>{

        public int compare(Player a, Player b){

            return a.player_name.compareTo(b.player_name);

        }
    }

}
```

/**Main method in java**/

```
package javapractice2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {         

        ArrayList<Player> ply = new ArrayList<Player>();

        ply.add(new Player ("kuldeep", 85));
        ply.add(new Player ("jadeja", 75));
        ply.add(new Player ("dohni", 48));
        ply.add(new Player ("kozhi", 78));
        ply.add(new Player ("raina", 48));
        ply.add(new Player ("sachin", 85));
        ply.add(new Player ("yuvaraj", 100));
        ply.add(new Player ("Ajinkya", 85));
        ply.add(new Player ("baji", 75));
        ply.add(new Player ("hardik", 55));

        Collections.sort(ply, new Sortbyname());

        for(int i=0; i<ply.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(ply.get(i));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Make it a static inner class with `public static class Sortbyname`.

Comment: Why is `Sortbyname` declared within another (useless) class?

Comment: thanks @Kayaman but it is not working.

Comment: @Michael take a reference from JavaTpoint website

Comment: Try `Collections.sort(ply, new NameComparator.Sortbyname());`

Answer (score 2):

Everything in your code is fine except the following inner class style code:

```
public class NameComparator {

public class Sortbyname implements Comparator<Player>{
```

So change this class as following:

Sortbyname.java

```
package javapractice2;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sortbyname implements Comparator<Player> {

    public int compare(Player a, Player b) {
        return a.player_name.compareTo(b.player_name);
    }
}
```

Also add a `toString()` method in Player.java for better output printing:

```
package javapractice2;

public class Player {
    String player_name;
    int player_score;

    public Player(String member, int score) {
        this.player_name = member;
        this.player_score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [player_name=" + player_name + ", player_score=" + player_score + "]";
    }

}
```

**Otherwise**, if you want to keep your code, then update the following in your Mainclass.java:

```
Collections.sort(ply, new NameComparator().new Sortbyname());
```

Answer (score 1):

Sortbyname is a nested class,

you need to create object for it as bellow,

```
new NameComparator.new Sortbyname();
```

go through below link for more information
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Correct answer but please consider the comments posted by Kayaman and Michael.

Comment: It is giving me compilation error - `No enclosing instance of type NameComparator is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type NameComparator (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of NameComparator).`

Comment: I completely agree with you Robert Kock,

Comment: Correct would be: `new NameComparator().new Sortbyname()`

Comment: Thanks for your Assists